# How to arrange different sizes controls in .net winform panels?

Tags: .net, winforms, layout, controls, panel

in a container panel I'm dropping controls of different sizes and I want them to organize without leaving empty spaces between them.

I tried using FlowLayoutPanel, but it leaves white space (if we use the Top Down option, two small controls might go next to each other, but the layout does not allow it and placed one below the other)

Is there any control that allows me to do this? Or of any known algorithm?

some data: Could define fixed sizes (eg 50x50, 100x50, 100x100)

I would like to do something like the navigation menu of windows 8 (The pictures are arranged according to size and importance) or else as pinterest (leaves no spaces between components)

I have (with flowlayoutpanel)
[image]

I want
[image]

I hope you can help me, thank you very much from now!

Comment: The empty spaces are due to the `Margin` and `Padding` properties. Each control has them, as does the container control (whether `Panel`, `TableLayoutPanel`, or `FlowLayoutPanel`). Change those to 0 for no whitespace (not recommended), or whatever values you want.

Comment: I mean empty spaces where they could be controls, not the margins (now edited the original post)

Comment: To get the level of control you are seeking you will most likely need to write the logic to position the controls. The Flow.. panels are just trying to mimic how a web page would flow.

Comment: You should be using `TableLayoutPanel` with which you can define a specific arrangement of rows and columns to arrive at the layout you want. See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.90).aspx